# Matriz Partida en R

Tags: r

En R hay rutinas para calcular operaciones como suma y restas, en este caso se las quiero aplicar a matrices partidas o también llamadas en bloques. Alguien sabe cuales son esas funciones para sumar y multiplicar matrices partidas? 
[image: a busy cat]

Gracias!

Comment: Es mejor que expongas con claridad qué estás haciendo y a qué problema te estás enfrentando. Si solo buscas ideas, opiniones o recomendaciones, te recomiendo que uses Google. Lee esta guia: [ask] y de ser posible edita tu pregunta para agregar un __[mcve]__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El recorte de matrices puede hacerse sin necesidad de funciones, simplemente hay que usar los operadores `[]` e indicar el conjunto de filas y columnas que vamos a recortar. Veamos tu ejemplo:

Creamos la matriz:

```
> m<-matrix(c(1,4,6,7,0,0,1,1,0,0,3,2),3,4, byrow=TRUE)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    6    7
[2,]    0    0    1    1
[3,]    0    0    3    2
```

Los primero dos recortes se hacen tomando fila 1 y dos columnas

```
> m[1,c(1,2)]

[1] 1 4

> m[1,c(3,4)]

[1] 6 7
```

Notese, que cuando solo queremos indicar 1 elemento no necesitamos la  función de creación de vectores `c()` por que `1` es un vector en sí mismo. Con el resto hacemos algo parecido:

```
> m[c(2,3),c(1,2)]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

> m[c(2,3),c(3,4)]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    3    2
```

Otra forma de recortar matrices más avanzada es recortar mediante otra matriz, primero creamos una matriz de recorte:

```
> c <- matrix(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,4,4),3,4, byrow=TRUE)
> c

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    2
[2,]    3    3    4    4
[3,]    3    3    4    4
```

Al ver la matriz queda claro que es lo que vamos a recortar, cada número indicará la matriz nueva que esperamos generar. Y ahora realizamos el recorte mediante [`split()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html), luego aplicamos [`lapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) para que cada recorte siga siendo una matiz y no un vector.

```
> lapply(split(m, c), matrix, nr = 2)

$`1`
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    4

$`2`
     [,1]
[1,]    6
[2,]    7

$`3`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

$`4`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    3    2
```

Como puedes ver, terminamos con una lista de las matrices que deseábamos originalmente

Comment: es una forma, pero si necesito las funciones porque necesito luego sumar esos bloques con otros de una matriz B. y que se unan en una nueva

Comment: @jose, agregué un ejemplo con `split()`

Comment: Si perfecto, ahora si hago eso mismo a una Matriz B y luego quiero sumar o multiplicar todas las submatrices de A y B y que queden guardadas en una nueva Variable, Como seria ?

Comment: @Jose, hay muchas formas y dependerá de como tengas cada matriz. En líneas generales las operación con matrices son tan sencillas como hacer `matriz1 + matriz2` o `matriz1 * matriz2`.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda